# Sudden SSH Connection to VM Instance Failure

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Suddenly today the SSH connection to my VM instance is taking a very long time without succeeding.

I would hate to repeat all of my work by creating a new instance. And, I don't know if the problem is related to disk space.

Can someone help.

Comment: establish your ssh connection with -vvv parameters and see what's happening. there are some components that works in every login. they are; /etc/update-motd-d, ~/.bashrc, /etc/profile etc. so check these files also. check if there is anything that blocks your ssh connection.

Comment: At first, you should collect logs: **1**. Go to Compute Engine -> VM instances -> click on NAME_OF_YOUR_VM -> at the VM instance details find section Logs and click on Serial port 1 (console) **2**. Reboot your VM instance (if possible). 3. Check full boot log for any errors or/and warnings. 4. Share full log by using [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com).

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should **collect logs**:

1. Go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on NAME_OF_YOUR_VM -> at the `VM instance details` find section **Logs** and click on `Serial port 1 (console)`
2. Reboot your VM instance again.
3. Check full boot log for any errors or/and warnings.

**If you found errors/warning related to disk space** you can try to resize it accordingly to the documentation [Resizing a zonal persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd), also accordingly to the article [Recovering an inaccessible instance or a full boot disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#inaccessible_instance):

> If an instance is completely out of disk space or if it is not running
> a Linux guest environment, then automatically resizing your root
> filesystem isn't possible, even after you've increased the size of the
> persistent disk that backs it. If you can't connect to your instance,
> or your boot disk is full and you can't resize it, you must create a
> new instance and recreate the boot disk from a snapshot to resize it.

Otherwise try to **troubleshoot your VM instance via serial console**:

1. [Enable serial console connection](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#enable_instance_access) with `gcloud` command:

   ```
    gcloud compute instances add-metadata NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE \
    --metadata serial-port-enable=TRUE
   ```

or go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> click on `EDIT` -> go to section **`Remote access`** and check `Enable connecting to serial ports`

2. Create temporary user and password to login: shutdown your VM and set a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) by adding at the section **`Custom metadata`** key `startup-script` and value:

   ```
    #!/bin/bash
    useradd --groups google_sudoers tempuser
    echo "tempuser:password" | chpasswd
   ```

and then start your VM.

3. [Connect to your VM via serial port](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole) with `gcloud` command:

   ```
    gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE
   ```

   or go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> and click on `Connect to serial console`
4. Check what went wrong.
5. [Disable access via serial port](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#disable_access) with `gcloud` command:

   ```
    gcloud compute instances add-metadata NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE \
    --metadata serial-port-enable=FALSE
   ```

or go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> click on `EDIT` -> go to section **`Remote access`** and uncheck `Enable connecting to serial ports`. Keep in mind that accordingly  to the documentation [Interacting with the serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console):

> **Caution**: The interactive serial console does not support IP-based access
> restrictions such as IP whitelists. If you enable the interactive
> serial console on an instance, clients can attempt to connect to that
> instance from any IP address. Anybody can connect to that instance if
> they know the correct SSH key, username, project ID, zone, and
> instance name. Use firewall rules to control access to your network
> and specific ports.

**If you weren't able to connect via serial console**, try follow the documentation [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) section [Inspect the VM instance without shutting it down](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh#inspect_vm) and **inspect the disk of your VM on another VM**. Same way you can transfer your data to another working VM instance.

Comment: @Fayez Was that helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me for to go on the VM instance and give it a reset. I did not lose anything and my WordPress site was still configured properly after the reset and could log back into the VM instance